# Assign foreach variables

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I've tried, believe me I've tried to figure this out but for the best part of the day it has beaten me so I have to ask this question:

I have a list ($list) of 100 words which I have put into an array:

`foreach ($tag_array as $key => $names ) {`

Each of these names I want to be a variable which I can use to assign some html for output within a html eg:

$arrayitem6 = 'whatever';

`print $arrayitem6;`

The reason I want to do this is because the 100 items in the list actually turns into 400 items in a html page which I would have to manually write out into a huge long repeating block of html. I want to create a single block of html/code using the array list and foreach.

I hope I've made myself understood. I'm sure it's a straight forward bit of coding but as a novice I cannot fathom.

thanks in advance for any help

I have searched the internet and googled but I can't locate an answer. I'll keep looking.

thanks

Comment: Have you checked `extract` http://php.net/extract

Comment: Hi, What is your need in output ?

Comment: `Each of these names I want to be a variable which I can use to assign some html for output within a html eg:` why you want soo. why complicating yourself.  so much variable? Also .html extension file not able to recognize php variables. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
<?php
foreach ($tag_array as $key => $names ) {
     ${"arrayitem$key"} = $names;
}
echo $arrayitem0;

?>
```

You can access variable as `$arrayitem0`, `$arrayitem0` and so on depending upon key (`$key`) of your `$tag_array`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
 <?php
     foreach ($tag_array as $key => $names ) {
      $."arrayitem".$key = $names;
   }
     echo $arrayitem6;

 ?>
```

you can access variable as $arrayitem0 ,$arrayitem1...till 99

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Those solutions helped me nail it.